# App's own image folder in UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, xcode, image, uiimagepickercontroller

How do I add an app's own images as a separate folder in a `UIImagePickerController` so the users can select them as well? Written in Swift 3?

This app (Quotiful) has successfully done this. They added their own at the bottom under the devices photo gallery:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a UIImagePicker to me. Are you sure it is? If you design your own image picker, you could probably set up something that appears like a separate folder by either using EXIF metadata or deep-linking.

Comment: It might be a custom `UIImagePickerController` (if that's possible to build?) So there's no way to easily just add another folder to it? @dfd

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, just another iOS coder trying to help. Considering the lack of other comments/answers, it may be. (If others have any better thoughts/answers, I'll gladly delete this!)

When Apple came out with iOS in 2008 they "hid" any kind of file system from everyone. They've exposed some things since by way of extensions (document, photo editing, iCloud, etc.), URL (deep linking), etc. But they always have kept tight control on a few things (security, sandboxing, etc.) and this may be one of those things.

My best guess is we're talking a combination of a subclassed UIImagePickerController (yes, you can do that) that can access something stored in the camera roll but is flagged in ways to make it appear as not. It takes effort (and resources), but sure, with a database (to hold your meta data including URL location) you can do this.

Again, I'm hoping someone can give a better (and easier to implement) answer.

Comment: Thank you for time!